# Python Google Drive APi v2 Search a file

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to search the Google Drive folder.
To check if there is not a folder with the name of the folder to create.
I have this code:

```
request_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?access_token=%s" % (access_token)     

data = {"q": "title=filename"}
data_json = json.dumps(data)
print data_json
req = urllib2.Request(request_url,data_json, headers)
print request_url
print data_json
content = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print content
content = json.loads(content)
```

Unfortunately, there is no research but creates a no name file.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files" means POST request for Metadata URI, for metadata-only requests.  To search a file you have to use file get. Refer to this page : https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get . Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Basically with urllib2, when you specify the data while using Request(), it automatically considers your request as a POST request, and that's why it creates a file with no name.

If you want it to be a GET request, you have to encode the data in the URL before calling Request()